# Pentaho use an Excel input with previous fields

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm  working with excel files in pentaho.

I do a preprocessing in directories because the information is stored in this way:

```
/[year_dir]/[mounth_dir]/[store_id]_[day_ofmount].xls

' example /2017/01/4567_3.xls means  03/01/2017 sells of the store 4567
```

and pass the filename to an **Excel input** but the information of `year,day ,store_id` the columns name are added to the begining shifting the rest of the columns names but not the data of the excel

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to include the filename (whole path) in your output data stream, then use a regex to split it into the various bits and pieces you need and extracting the date and store id from there.

You can later have a select values step to re-order the fields if order is important.

Comment: but why insert the colums names and shift in that way?

Comment: Because fields are added in the order they’re created. If order maters you may need to re-order.